# Collect Information From Database Then Insert It Into Other Table?

Tags: mysql, database, submit

I have a page where the user submits the name of an item (Term) and finds information about the item. So the database find the Name ('Items') and the Location ('Loc') and echos it to the user. Now they may want to keep track of this information to create a list of items and their location. So I used a form where you import your username, password, item, and location. This is so they can get the information in 2 hours if they want. I would like to keep the form as small as it can be so I want to eliminate the user from having to insert the item name and location. Is there a way to get the echoed information and submit it through the form without the user having to? Thanks for any help provided!

```
$term = $_POST['term'];

$query = mysql_query("select * from List where Items = '$term'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) <= 0)
{
echo "<center>No results. Please try another item.</center>";
} else {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo ' <br/>Item - '.$row['Items'];
echo ' <br/>Location - '.$row['Loc'];
echo '<br/><br/>';

}
}
?>
</p1>
<center>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<div><label for="Username">Username : </label><input type="text" name="Username" />  </div>
<div><label for="Password">Password: </label><input type="text" name="Password" /></div>
<div><label for="Items">Items: </label><input type="text" name="Items" /></div>
<div><label for="Loc">Location: </label><input type="text" name="Loc" /></div>
<P><label for="submit"></label><input type="submit" /></P>
</form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.........

```
 $query1="select sm.id, IFNULL(sm.unit_price,0) as unit_price       
       from crm_stock_manager sm
       left join crm_purchase_order_items poi on poi.id = sm.purchase_order_item_id and  poi.is_del = 0
       left join crm_products p on poi.product_id = p.id and p.is_del = 0
       where sm.is_del = 0 and IFNULL(sm.unit_price, '') != '' and p.id = 253 order by sm.created_on;"
    $query1_res = mysql_query($query1);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query1_res) <= 0)
        $query2="select price from crm_products where id = 253  and is_del=0";

    $query1_res = mysql_query($query2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To optimize performance make procedure rather than firing 2 queries from your code. Because store procedure is pre compile and you can pass request parameter inside that.